# Knockout. Print two properties of an object in a foreach statement

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have an observableArray property `self.FilteredStudents`, the students have name and lastname, and i want to print it together.

Here is the foreach code in the HTML:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" data-bind="foreach: FilteredStudents">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div>
                        <div class="LLUserCard">
                            <div class="LLUserCardHeader">
                                <div>$name $lastName</div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="LLUserCardBody">

                            </div>
                            <div class="LLUserCardFooter">
                                $enrollmentDate
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Obviously the code above is not working, the pseudocode `<div>$name $lastName</div>` is just to specify what i am looking for.

In all the examples or tutorials i've found they use two elements like `<td data-bind="text: name"></td><td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>` but i don't want to print the values in different elements, i want them to be the text of one element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a computed or pure computed function or an inline function on the text binding https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/69/

html

```
<p>
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </p>
      <p>
      Or
      </p>
      <span data-bind="text: (firstname() + ' ' + lastname() )"></span>
```

js

```
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.firstname = ko.observable('bob');
   this.lastname = ko.observable('smith');

  self.Name = ko.pureComputed(function () {
             return self.firstname() + ' '  + self.lastname()
        },this);
}


var vm = new viewModel();


(function($) {
  ko.applyBindings(vm); //bind the knockout model
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you, your first option is not applicable to my question because i'm inside a foreach loop, so i can't make an observable for each name and lastName of the objects, and the computed property need those obseervable to work. But, your second solution works perfectly... Could you please explain why introducing a javascript statement between parenthesis actually executes the statement? Or at least, where in the documentation could i find a reference to that?

Comment: it works exactly the same for a foreach loop.... https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/73/

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html  states "he binding value can be a single value, variable, or literal or almost any valid JavaScript expression. "

Comment: Ok, you are right, it is far more complicated than with the second option, but it also works. And thank you for the documentation reference, I've learnd a lot  with your answers ;)